# How to get the "encryption method" string for a mounted drive in VeraCrypt from the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, veracrypt

I am trying to determine which encryption method each of my mounted VeraCrypt drives use, from PHP CLI, which means "from the command line".

I find no such feature in the VeraCrypt manual for command line options.

I'm imagining something like:

```
veracrypt.exe --determine-encryption-method-for-disk "C:"
```

Which would, for example, return a string such as:

```
Serpent
```

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### I am trying to determine which encryption method each of my mounted VeraCrypt drives use

Looking at the command line options which are documented at [VeraCrypt - Free Open source disk encryption with strong security for the Paranoid - VeraCrypt Documentation](https://documentation.help/VeraCrypt/Command%20Line%20Usage.html) this does not seem to be supported.

Note:

> In VeraCrypt, information about the encryption algorithm or the KDF is never saved in the disk header.

Source: [Breaking VeraCrypt: Obtaining and Extracting On-The-Fly Encryption Keys | ElcomSoft blog](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2021/06/breaking-veracrypt-obtaining-and-extracting-on-the-fly-encryption-keys/)

Comment: I don't know what your point is about the quote. Obviously, VeraCrypt knows which encryption algorithm was used for mounted disks, since they are mounted. And it also displays this in the list of mounted drives as a column.

Comment: The point is that will be no alternative cli methods of getting at what you want.